# Passing data from web api on the main page to the details page in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, picker

Here is how my code looks like for the page that has data:

```
private async Task GetLeaveBalance() {
    try
    {
        Uri = "http://192.168.42.35/API/api/leave/getbalance/"+ empId + "/"+ companyId;
        client = new HttpClient();

        var authHeaderValue = basic;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeaderValue);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Uri);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Leave>>(responseBody);
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = emp;
            UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
        Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
        UserDialogs.Instance.ShowError(e.Message);
    }
}

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new Details());
}
```

My Second page(Details Page) has a picker which needs to be  populated by data that I get from the emp variable so how can I pass data from the first page to the second page(Details Page)?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Session variables, cookies, querystring,  ... but why not request the data from the API again when you visit the details page? This is the most safe way in any case

Comment: Can Sessions store list data ?

Comment: It can store any object you want. You'll have to cast it back to the right type after getting it out of the session though.

Comment: But there's no session management API in xamarin forms

Comment: Are you using MVVM approach in your application? If yes, why not using either same ViewModel or sharing the data between the ViewModels.
Generally, it is not good idea to have this kind of code in your code-behind.

Comment: No, I'm not using MVVM approach

Comment: @PhulusoRamulifho, Why would you rely on events to send data that could have been send directly! It works, but not proper way to do. Messaging center has different use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass through MessagingCenter aswell, here is some steps.

First in your SecondPage you register an messagingcenter task.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SecondPage(you can create a empty interface if you want to use as type),string>(this, "PopulateSecondPage", (sender,DataFromMainPage) =>
            {
                //your code to handle DataFromMainPage
            });
```

then pass the data using

```
    var page = new SecondPage();

    Navigation.PushAsync(page);

   MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(page, "PopulateSecondPage","Data you want to pass");
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering your approach and code you can directly pass data to the constructor of your second page

```
List<Leave> leaves = new List<Leave>();

private async Task GetLeaveBalance() {
    ...
    leaves = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Leave>>(responseBody);
    ...
}

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new Details(leaves));
}
```